# How to display a popup message in Roblox game mode?

Tags: lua, roblox

I'm trying to parse chat messages for keywords that I will use to trigger various functions. In order to use the chat I have to test in game mode, which is started by first clicking Tools-> Test-> Start Server and then clicking Tools-> Test-> Start Player. The command window is not available in game mode so I need a way to get some debugging feedback. I figured a popup message would be good for that purpose.

I suspect its fairly simple to display a popup message but I cant find any information on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you enable the Output window?

```
View -> Output menu
```

Then e.g. if you script does

```
print("Hello world!")
```

You should see that in the output window. Else take a look at

[How to add messages](http://wiki.roblox.com/index.php/How_to_add_messages)

Comment: Yes I enabled the output window and it works great in solo mode, but you cant use chat in solo mode. Chat will only work in game mode, but the output window will not display in game mode.

Comment: The link to How to add messages was very useful. Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Enable the output,
Press Test >> Start Server
In that new window press Test >> Start Player
In the server window (Not the new player window), open the command bar and type:

```
game.Players.Player.SuperSafeChat = false
```

And press enter.
You can test it, and get output.

Answer (score 0):

to see the output, go into the server window, and make sure the output window is shown.

Answer (score 0):

While the following answers are of course correct, you CAN create a popup to display output from the...output. This can be done by overriding the default "print" function:

```
_G["dprint"] = _G.print
_G["print"] = function(...)
   pargs = {...}
   lMessage = Instance.new("Message")
   lMessage.Parent = workspace
   lMessage.Text = table.concat(pargs, " ") -- Is it concat?
   wait(10)
   lMessage:remove()
```

end

Comment: This do not work anymore, to fix this try use getfenv()["print"] instead. Also to be noted is that while print() allows you to pass Userdata, your script would break. And that your script would make all print() calls wait for 10 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

```
native.showAlert(parameters list)
```

This can be best way to implement.

Comment: Sorry I haven't tested on ROBLOX environment. Sorry once again.

Answer (score 0):

There are some ways you can achieve this.

1. Roblox recently added a [developer console](http://wiki.roblox.com/index.php?title=Developer_console) that you can also use in game, so basically you can see the output window even online.
2. [You can use Messages or Hints](http://wiki.roblox.com/index.php/How_to_add_messages)
3. [You can make your own GUI](http://wiki.roblox.com/index.php?title=Beginner%27s_GUI_Tutorial)
4. If you don't need it online, you can use the [output window](http://wiki.roblox.com/index.php?title=Output).

Answer (score 0):

[ROBLOX](http://www.roblox.com/) has actually added a developer console (see it at the wiki: wiki.roblox.com/index.php?title=Developer_console) to the game client AND added its availability to studio 2015. You can access using the `f9` button (or `alt+f9` on laptops). You could've also opened the  output window (see it at the wiki: wiki.roblox.com/index.php?title=Output) and see the errors there. Hope this helped!